# CodeIginter 3 Email Library $to field doesn't work, but $cc does

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a simple function that emails out a reminder message. I'm using CodeIginter 3 and it's Email Library. When I run the Controller from my test machine it works fine, but when I run it from my webserver it will only send the emails to those listed in the $cc or $bcc fields, anyone listed as the recipient ($to) won't get any email.

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $lateE = $this->Equipment_model->get_late_equipment_report();

    foreach($lateE as $le){

        $this->email->from('no-reply@server.com', 'Reminder');
        $this->email->to($le->email,'test1@server.com','test2@yahoo.com'); 
        $this->email->cc('test3@gamil.com');  
        $this->email->bcc('test4@yahoo.com'); 
        $this->email->subject('Late Reminder');

        $mail = "This message is a reminder that you have checked out Equipment \n\r\n\r";

        $mail .=" Name: ". $le->first ." ". $le->last ."\n\r";
        $mail .=" Reminder: ". $le->pack ."\n\r";
        $mail .=" Due back on: ". $le->returndate ."\n\r\n\r"; 

        $this->email->message($mail);   

        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `to` field *does* work. But not with multiple parameters:

Email.php *(~600)*:

```
/**
 * Set Recipients
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  CI_Email
 */
public function to($to)
```

It's expecting a single string.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give it a try